On intersection theory on toric varieties
Let $\Delta$ be a polytope and consider the projective toric variety $P_{\Delta}.$
Given a curve $C \subset \mathbb{P}_{\Delta},$ which is not toric, is it true that in the Chow group we have
$$ C = \sum_{\sigma} c_\sigma [V(\sigma)] , \quad c_\sigma > 0 \quad \text{ for each } \sigma?$$
$V(\sigma)$ is the orbit closure corresponding to a cone $\sigma$ of the normal fan of $\Delta.$

No, let $P_\Delta= (\mathbb P^1)^3$ and let $C$ be a curve in $(\mathbb P^1)^2$. Then the Chow group of curves in $\mathbb P_\Delta$ is freely generated by copies of $\mathbb P^1$ in the three directions $[h], [w], [l]$, with each arising as $[V(\sigma)]$ for four cones $\sigma$. Since $C = x [h]+y[w]+0 [l]$ for some $x,y$, any expression of $C$ as a sum of $c_\sigma [V(\sigma)]$ cannot have $c_\sigma>0$ for all four $\sigma$ with $[V(\sigma)]=[l]$.

Is it still true if one relaxes the condition to $c_\sigma \ge 0,$ that is, does there exist $c_\sigma \ge 0,$ such that $C \equiv \sum_{\sigma} c_\sigma  [V(\sigma)]$?

@user535880 Sure, look at the translates of $C$ by a one-parameter subgroup of the torus, and then take the limit. The limit is equivalent to $C$ but invariant under the one parameter-subgroup, so each component is either a one-dimensional torus orbit or fixed by that subgroup and thus contained in a lower-dimensional toric variety. Now do induction.
